# Returned "undefined" error when post the data to Json

Tags: json

I want to test my ajax 'PUT' function when passing a parameter 1 but it returned undefined??

```
orders.json
```

[
    {
    "id" : 1,
    "name": "will_1",
    "drink" : "cola_2"
    },
    {
    "id" : 2,
    "name": "Laura",
    "drink" : "vanilla"
    }
]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#purchaseId").change(function() { 

        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'orders.json',
          data: "1",
          success:function(newOrder) {
            
              alert(newOrder.name);
            
          },
      
          error:function(){
            alert("loading error");
        }       
        
      });

  });

});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>       
     <script src="home.js">
     </script>
     
    <title>Javascript on Steroids</title>
</head>
<body> 

   
        <select id = "purchaseId"  >
            <option value="1" selected >1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you POST or PUT, you are sending `data: "1",` which only sends the parameter, but not it's value.. In GET it would look like: `//someurl/?1=`

Try: `data: "order=1",` which will POST/PUT a parameter: `order` with value: `1`

This way on the backend you can expect the `$_POST['order']`, and will grab its sent value of `1`

Comment: sorry not understand..><..sorry too new to tis ajax

Comment: try to replace `data: "1",` with `data: "order=1",` in your code

Comment: Also as you are new to ajax, and using jquery, get to know the documentation, as it should be clear enough there with examples: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType

Comment: I already study this link u gave me, but still return undefined. it seems like new data submit cannot pass to server json to store data?

Comment: is there any related with my Apache server, cause I'm using local server XAMPP

Comment: Even I inspect the console the json data still remain same no adding new data to it.

Comment: When you POST to `orders.json` what is the backend doing? are you using PHP? or are you posting to a static orders.json file ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nL7X1UMWsc&t=300s I refer to tis utube but it not working for me..dunno why..T.T

Comment: The Tutorial use Express framework as backend, which will modify in someway the POST data you send to the Backend.. but you are saying that `orders.json` is a static text file on your end? You cannot expect a static text or json file to return anything to you when you post to it.. You either need a nodejs API (Express) as a backend, or PHP backend, or Python backend, etc, so that when you push a given (and expected) parameter with it's value, that backend WORKS on it, and returns some result.. with your setup this is not happening, correct? Nothing gets WORKED as `orders.json` is simply static

Comment: Hello Ron, tq for the answer, I use php as my backend to retrieve the data in json, issit possible to break and get the specific data I want by using ajax post query after I encode all the php data in the backend to json. Because I have try $("#result").html(data.name) but no data appear.

Answer (score 0):

$.post("getdata.php",{
        id:productId
      }, function(data,status){

```
    $("#result").html(data);
```

});